# Black Sholes option pricing with all but Delta

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, implied-volatility, derivatives, delta

I'm trying to setup a little option pricing model in excel. I have all the information for the inputs (interest rate, IVs for different deltas, time to expiry, strike price, underlying price) but what I do not have is the actual delta for which I should be drawing the IVs from.
To clarify, I have a list of IVs for each possible delta you want for the underlying security. But it's as if you're in an endless loop because you don't know what IV list to choose since it's linked to a specific delta: which you do not know.

Attaching a Delta formula in case it helps anyone visualize things.

I do not have the actual call prices since I'm dealing with illiquid cases and the end goal is to calculate those prices.

Thanks.

[image: Black Sholes Delta formula]

Comment: This image looks familiar 

Comment: Anyway. Welcome to Quant stackexchange. To me, it is unclear what exactly you’re asking about. Consider editing your question with more precise formulation.

Comment: I find it hard to understand what information you have and what information you are trying to compute. Generally untraded options don't have an IV. You would have to use the historical volatility (HV) for the underlying stock. Do you have a price history for the underlying stock?

Comment: Does it relate to FX options where the IV is quoted by delta?

Comment: @Magicisinthechain, it's not FX, the underlying are commodity futures, so to be treaded simply as any non-dividend paying futures

Comment: I am trying to compute the historical price of a call option based on inputs (strike, IR, time to expiry) which I plug to the forward curves to get the stock price - so I do have the price history for the underlying stock. Now, I also have a table with IVs for any delta you want. And yes because it goes back in time some of those become historical volatilities but ignore that. The issue is - how do I figure out which delta I should be taking the corresponding IV from? Hope this clarifies it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you have the implied vol by delta, and you would like to calculate the price using the Black Scholes formula. And I assume you know the other inputs-e.g., underlying price, interest rate and maturity. Very typical problem in the FX world, so what you can do is first convert delta (using the other inputs and vol) to strike, and then you have vol by strike, which you can then plug into the BS to get the price. The delta comes in different shades, but if it is the simple unadjusted delta, then you can easily isolate strike on one side:

$\Delta=N\left(d_1\right)$

$d_1=N^{-1} \left(\Delta\right)$

Then substitute the expression for $d_1$ and solve for K.

$K=S e^{\left(r +0.5\sigma^2\right)T-\sigma \sqrt{T}N^{-1}\left(\Delta\right)}$

Now you have vol by strike, which you can use with the other inputs to calculate the price.

Comment: More details on how this work in FX on this page https://quantpie.co.uk/fx/strikes_given_vol_delta.php that I contributed to.

Comment: Ah I see so that I'd have a mapping by strike price rather than a mapping by delta, and then come back to it afterwards. Thanks a lot

Comment: Indeed, and the reason this style is used is because underlying is moving all the time so delta provides a better reference point. Once all the terms have been agreed then you can base the option on the most recent market reference point.

Comment: This conversion assumes a sticky strike. Given that the vols are being quoted in delta, this is probably not correct.

Comment: Thanks @will. Do you mind highlighting which part need changing please? I thought the question was about simple conversion rather than smile modelling, as the smile is already given.

Comment: Under the circumstances sticky delta assumption, the vol is a function of delta, the smile as a function of strike changes as the spot changes, because the delta of the options all changes. I'm not aware of a closed form solution, you need to iterate.

Comment: I do appreciate the difference between sticky delta and the sticky strike as in these slides(http://www.math.columbia.edu/~smirnov/Derman.pdf), but I thought the underlying price is known as per the wording. Do you mind writing the iteration in another answer please, it would be very useful.

Comment: Or alternatively, please feel free to edit the answer if you like.